# Different between javascript regex and swift regex

Tags: javascript, swift, unicode, ios9

Recently I have created a regex for swift from javascript regex to detect unicode font and other font which doesn't follow unicode standant. But now I got the problem with converting it. The problem is `\s\u1031` javascript regex pattern doesn't allow in swift.

```
var regexZG = new RegExp("\s\u1031|\u1031[^\u1000-\u1021\u103b\u1040\u106a\u106b\u107e-\u1084\u108f\u1090]| ေ[က-အ]်|[က-အ]း","g");
```

How can I rewrite this in swift and it will work in the swift as well?

Answer (score 2):

Swift has a different syntax for arbitrary unicode characters, `\u{n}`.

> An arbitrary Unicode scalar, written as \u{n}, where n is a 1–8 digit hexadecimal number with a value equal to a valid Unicode code point

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293

So, in your case it's `\u{1031}` instead of `\u1031`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is probably wrong in Javascript, too.  Using `new RegExp()` with a literal string means that the regex has to get through the string literal parsing before it's parsed as a regular expression. That, in turn, means that `\s` turns into a plain `s` - matching a literal "s", not whitespace.

In Swift, you can't put a backslash in front of arbitrary characters, so you get an `invalid escape sequence in literal` error.

In Javascript, you should use a regex literal instead:

```
var regexZG = /\s\u1031|\u1031[^\u1000-\u1021\u103b\u1040\u106a\u106b\u107e-\u1084\u108f\u1090]| ေ[က-အ]်|[က-အ]း/g;
```

In Swift, you need to double the backslashes in special regex sequences like `\s`.

The other issue is that Unicode escapes in swift are of the form `\u{XXXX}` instead of just `\uXXXX`, so you need to ut curly braces around all the code point values in your `\u` expressions.

So the Swift version looks something like this:

```
"\\s\u{1031}|\u{1031}[^\u{1000}-\u{1021}\u{103b}\u{1040}\u{106a}\u{106b}\u{107e}-\u{1084}\u{108f}\u{1090}]| ေ[က-အ]်|[က-အ]း"
```